# error: failed to parse manifest at `/home/sourav/Rust/Course2/Cargo.toml`

Tags: rust

I ran `cargo init .` to create a new project. I then ran `cargo run` and I get this message:

```
error: failed to parse manifest at `/home/sourav/Rust/Course2/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  no targets specified in the manifest
  either src/lib.rs, src/main.rs, a [lib] section, or [[bin]] section must be present
```

My Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "crates"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
authors = ["Sourav Goswami"]

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
humantime = "2.1.0"

[[bin]]
name = "test"
path = "src/main.rs"
```

Problem is that the I'm sitting under `/home/sourav/Rust/Course2/crates/` directory and  the location cargo gives `/home/sourav/Rust/Course2/Cargo.toml` isn't correct:

```
$ pwd
/home/sourav/Rust/Course2/crates

$ \ls -lisha -R
.:
total 8.0K
  2201181    0 drwxr-xr-x 3 sourav sourav   35 Jan 23 02:17 .
271282604 4.0K drwxr-xr-x 9 sourav sourav 4.0K Jan 23 02:17 ..
  2201170 4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 sourav sourav  268 Jan 23 02:35 Cargo.toml
137280290    0 drwxr-xr-x 2 sourav sourav   21 Jan 23 02:17 src

./src:
total 4.0K
137280290    0 drwxr-xr-x 2 sourav sourav  21 Jan 23 02:17 .
  2201181    0 drwxr-xr-x 3 sourav sourav  35 Jan 23 02:17 ..
137280296 4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 sourav sourav 154 Jan 23 02:26 main.rs
```

Contents of parent directory:

```
\ls -lh
total 21M
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sourav sourav 3.6M Jan  8 01:10 activity-impl
-rw-r--r-- 1 sourav sourav 1.1K Jan  8 01:10 activity-impl.rs
drwxr-xr-x 4 sourav sourav   67 Jan 12 12:27 advanced
-rw-r--r-- 1 sourav sourav  176 Jan 23 02:14 Cargo.toml
drwxr-xr-x 3 sourav sourav   35 Jan 23 02:17 crates
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sourav sourav 3.5M Jan  3 23:06 data1
drwxr-xr-x 2 sourav sourav  204 Jan  8 02:23 datastructures
-rw-r--r-- 1 sourav sourav  348 Jan  5 23:53 demo_ownership.rs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sourav sourav 3.5M Jan  4 01:01 enum_and_struct
-rw-r--r-- 1 sourav sourav  609 Jan  4 01:01 enum_and_struct.rs
-rw-r--r-- 1 sourav sourav  347 Jan  3 23:28 enum.rs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sourav sourav 3.5M Jan  7 14:40 impl
-rw-r--r-- 1 sourav sourav  697 Jan  7 14:40 impl.rs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sourav sourav 3.5M Jan  5 14:09 ownership
-rw-r--r-- 1 sourav sourav  414 Jan  5 14:10 ownership.rs
drwxr-xr-x 4 sourav sourav   67 Jan 15 17:38 project
drwxr-xr-x 4 sourav sourav   67 Jan 15 16:37 real_world
drwxr-xr-x 4 sourav sourav   67 Jan 21 04:13 refining_code
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sourav sourav 3.5M Jan  3 23:44 struct
-rw-r--r-- 1 sourav sourav  394 Jan  3 23:44 struct.rs
```

Why is cargo searching the parent directory instead of the current working directory? How do I fix this issue without moving the directory or touching the parent directory?

EDIT

1. If I rename or remove the cargo from the parent directory, all things are working correctly.
2. If I move the Cargo.toml to the parent directory of the parent directory (~/Rust/). The same problem happens.
3. If I again move Cargo.toml to `/home/sourav/`, then go to the Project folder (~/Rust/Course2/crates) I get:

```
error: failed to parse manifest at `/home/sourav/Cargo.toml`
```

4. If I go to /, and create Cargo.toml, again go to the project folder (~/Rust/Course2/crates) I get this:

```
error: failed to parse manifest at `/Cargo.toml`
```

So it looks like rust scans for Cargo.toml file in the parent directories and if there are no such file, it will keep descending into the PWD while scanning each parent directories. That surely gave me a lot of insights and in the future I have to be careful while creating a Cargo.toml file in any of the parent directories. Keeping it in `/` is worst because it breaks all the projects.

Comment: Where did that `cargo/` subfolder come from? Did you create it manually?

Comment: You've got a package name `crates` but a directory name `cargo`, which suggests you rearranged some things after initializing. Please [edit] your question to show us a listing of exactly what files are in `/home/sourav/Rust/Course2/` and its subdirectories, and the contents of any `Cargo.toml`s present besides the one you've already shown.

Comment: Regarding the creation, no I ran `cargo init .`. Of course, the parent directory has Cargo.toml for some reason. But that's the question - why is the parent directory affecting my current project? Also thank you, I have edited the question to include more details.